automatically label subfigure overlapping top left
I have a set of subfigures that I want to label like (a) but without any real caption,
and I want to place the labels (a) on top of the graphic,
in the top-left corner to save vertical space.
I want to specify graphic widths, not heights,
so the label placement must be automatic.
I also want this behaviour to be optional, so that other subfigures are not affected.
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for graphics
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigure
\usepackage{tikz} % for demo only
% demo
\begin{document}
Figure~\ref{fig:main}.
\begin{figure}[h]
  \foreach \var in {a,b,c}{\hskip0pt
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \caption{\hfill\null}\label{fig:\var}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-\var}
  \end{subfigure}}
  \caption{Overall caption.
    (\subref{fig:a}) details;
    (\subref{fig:b}) details;
    (\subref{fig:c}) details.}
  \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Desired Result


Here is a solution by hacking around with \vspace,
but it requires the subfigure content be passed to a pseudo-caption command \overlaption
so that the height is known.
Maybe there are better ways...
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for graphics
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigure
\usepackage{tikz} % for demo only
% solution
\newlength{\fskip} % dummy
\newlength{\fgap}\setlength{\fgap}{1ex}
\newcommand{\overlaptions}{%
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=\fgap,margin=\fgap,singlelinecheck=false}}
\newcommand{\overlaption}[2][]{
  \setbox0=\vbox{#2}\fskip=\ht0% get the content height
  #2\vspace{-\fskip}\caption{}\label{#1}% ship content & caption
  \vspace{\dimexpr\fskip-\baselineskip-\belowcaptionskip-\fgap}}% reset position
% demo
\begin{document}
Figure~\ref{fig:main}.
\begin{figure}[h]
  \overlaptions
  \foreach \var in {a,b,c}{\hskip0pt
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \overlaption[fig:\var]
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-\var}}%\\some extra text}
  \end{subfigure}}
  \caption{Overall caption.
    (\subref{fig:a}) details;
    (\subref{fig:b}) details;
    (\subref{fig:c}) details.}
  \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Result

